# Importing PDF document as artwork

Tags: adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I am a newbie in Adobe LiveCycle. My requirement is to place a layered pdf (smaller than A4) as background and insert a runtime generated barcode into the pdf artwork. I found few guidelines about importing artwork in Adobe LiveCycle Designer [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/designerHelp/index.htm?content=000194.html). 
The problem I am facing is when I generate PDF, the barcode is inserted above the template and whole design is messed. How can I configure the position of dynamically inserted element?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: 
I get this output. [image: this]. Dynamic element is at right position but pdf artwork is moved down.

EDIT 2:

[image: Hierarchy window]

Comment: could you provide your _hierarchy_ window in the question?
This could also have something to do with your _Layout_ or _Object_ tab or any code you have running on startup.

Comment: @Cold_Class, I have attached the screenshot of hierarchy window.

Comment: So...is either one (the dynamic element or the artwork) in the hierarchy - what is that *TextField1*?
I never tried what you found in those guidelines before, but whenever I need any background that is not supposed to move and be independent from anything else I just use a *Masterpage* for that, maybe that info could help you.

Comment: @Cold_Class, Thanks. TextField1 is dynamic content. Can you please provide any link that would be useful to create masterpage ( I am not able to see any option like masterpage in Designer)?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/designerHelp/index.htm?content=000076.html
But I just noticed they don't always work, one has to let LCD convert a PDF into a dynamic PDF first I think, maybe you could try that.